# Microsoft Visual Studio: Extremely slow at compiling (Unreal Engine source code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to compile [this version](https://github.com/narknon/UnrealEngine-CEEnd/tree/4.27-chaos) of Unreal Engine and the tutorial says it would take between 10 and 40 minutes, a tutorial video said it took two hours, I've been running it since three hours and this is the last log I can see:

3>  [175/4741] Module.DeveloperSettings.gen.cpp

It literally prints one every 10 minutes or even more!
At this rate it will take several days, this is impossible... that must be something wrong in my configuration or in my PC.

These are my specs:
CPU: Intel Core i7 4770 GPU: Sapphire Radeon RX 570 RAM: 8 GBs

The source code is in a HDD device but the operative system and Microsoft Visual Studio is running on an SSD.
I just installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Community Edition and I made no change in configuration.
Do you have any idea? I also tried manually rising up the priority of the processes which was set to low.

Comment: Your link in your post leads to a 404 not found.  Check to make sure your computer isn't in a power saving mode. That may help a bit. But something tells me that compiling the entire unreal engine may take some times on what is now a fairly old machine it sounds like.

Comment: Nope, it's not in power saving mode... about the GitHub link it also gives me that error in my phone but not in my desktop, weird.

Comment: Make sure the build tree has been excluded from any virus scanners.  Perhaps the source tree and system headers as well.

Comment: Compiling c++ code from a hard disk is fundamentally slow, the compiler reads lots of little files, just about the worst case for hdd performance. Make sure you've got plenty of free ram to improve disk caching and the compiler needs a fair amount too for some files. If you run out of ram and start swapping to disk the compilation will pretty much grind to a halt (sounds like this is your issue). Checking task managers performance metrics should lead you to the problem, whichever of disk, memory or cpu is maxed out is your bottleneck

Comment: I should have generated the source code in the SSD... Probably just moving the folder may take a lot of time...
But probably the RAM is the bottleneck, by the way, since it's at 60/80%, CPU is below 10% and disk below 20%.

Comment: Intel Core i7 4470 is 4th generation Core CPU.  It was launched in 2013Q2, and discontinued 2017-Jul-14.  Upshot being:  it's a little old, and a bit slower than the current 12th generation Core CPUs. Still... seems quite a bit slower than it should be.

Comment: Yeah like it would faster to me to manually convert source to machine code on paper.

Comment: "I just installed" => disable the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: Can you add more RAM?  DDR-3 sticks are very cheap these days. 
 You can get them on eBay, pulled from old systems, and, in my experience, they work fine.